# When there is only one option in a drop down list in IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, mobile

When there is only one option in a drop down list, IOS auto selects that option but Android won’t have the option selected until you click on the drop down arrow and select that option. You still can open the drop down list in IOS. But I feel like have the only option auto selected is more convenient for the user. I am wondering if the difference is the nature of the platform or if it is something that I can change in Android to match in IOS.

Comment: iOS will not default by-default. You must have written code for the same.

Write code for same in Android too...

Comment: Can you change the behavior of Android? No. Can you change the behavior of your app to auto-select the only option? Sure you can.